# Regex that worked on Sublime not working on Pycharm

Tags: regex, pycharm

Ok so, in Sublime Text I can use this Find/Replace regex:

```
find: (src|href)="(assets\/.+?)"
replace: \1="{% static '\2' %}"
```

To replace this

```
<link href="assets/css/cssfile.css">
```

With this:

```
<link href="{% static 'assets/css/cssfile.css' %}"/>
```

When I use the same regexes in Pycharm, it doesn't replace the values correctly.. is it a regex problem or a Pycharm problem? I'm not sure since I'm kind of new to regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the [PyCharm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/finding-and-replacing-text-in-file.html#d896053e445), in PyCharm you need to use $1 rather than \1 to refer to a group in the replacement expression.